# HTML TD Clickable

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a menu you can see on the top right hand side - www.balibar.co

HTML:

```
    <div id="joinHeader" class="shadow">
            <table id="indexNavigation"><tr>
                <td><a id="navSearch">Search</a></td>
                <td><a id="navLanguages">Languages</a></td>
                <td id="activeNavLink"><a id="navLogin">Login</a></td>
            </tr></table>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 table#indexNavigation {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1.1em;
border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 table#indexNavigation td {
text-align: center;
color: white;
width: 33.33%;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
cursor: pointer;
 }

table#indexNavigation td#activeNavLink {
border-right: none;
 }
```

I want to make the entire TD Clickable.
I've added cursor: pointer; to the TD but it doesn't light up except when over the words.
I tried putting the `<a>` outside the `<td>` but this didn't work.

Is there a trick to make this clickable.
Will then hook this up to jQuery for a click event - e.g.:

```
 $('td#activeNavLink').click(function() {
```

Comment: Cannot you make `<td onclick="..">`

Comment: This should really be a list, not a table.

Comment: ya I was using a list but the table just sits perfectly...

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `display:block` in your CSS.

Here's an example from an unordered list (ul) with block-links: [link](http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000230.php)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your links inside your `td` tags have a width of 100%. Then they will take up the full width of the cell.

```
table#indexNavigation td a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Wait, I think I see - I forgot the `a` in my css definition.

Answer (score -1):

you have two options

1. by css only

   here you actually make the anchor tag a block element, give it full width and height to make it as big as the table cell...

   ```
   table td a {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
   ```

   **remark** you might need to move some paddings and such from the `TD` element to the `A` element
2. by javascript

   this means, adding a click event to the `td` element, and then triggering the click from the anchor element that's inside that table cell.

   ```
   $('#mytable td').each(function(){
     $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'}).click(function(){
       $(this).find('a:first').trigger('click');
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use javascript to do this and recommending unnecessary javascript is almost never good advice.

Comment: eh the OP himself asks to do it trough javascript, and to be fair i gave both options! never said that using the extra javascript is better than using css only. and to be frank, the only pro that the javascript holds over css is that it works everywhere, with the css it largly depends on the layout and which browsers you would need to make it work in.

Comment: never said it does not work, but you have to agree its not as simple as `width: 100%` and `display: block`. there is the height, which might need to be auto, depending on the row height and the content of other columns, there is the padding which suddenly needs to move to the A element instead of the td. etc etc

Comment: padding was the trick... adding in the right padding for each (had to be different because there was different number of characters)... once this was in the cursor would change when entering the cell and I could get the click event - jquery - I needed working... thx...

Comment: @Adam - that's a really poor way to go about it - what happens when you have another one? Now you need to figure out the padding again. Just setting the width on the `a` tag works perfectly in all situations. Why *wouldn't* you use that?