# HTML : Clickable td elements for checkers

Tags: html, tags, html-table, clickable

Trying to make td elements clickable. Here's my HTML:

```
<td id="A3" class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/A3"></a></td>
```

and my CSS:

```
table td a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I tried to follow the advice of this similar question : [HTML TD Clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555163/html-td-clickable)

But it didn't seem to work. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: So it kinda works if I insert a &nbsp inside the a tag, but it leaves a line there thats ugly. It's at least clickable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a height as well.

```
table td a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;}
```